# correct xsl template matching syntax

Tags: xslt

I'm learning XSL and hope to get some help. I want to extract part of the following datasets.xml and output them as tab delimited texts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<listDatasetsResponse xmlns="http://www.algorithmics.com/schema">
        <status>OK</status>
        <datasets size="31">
            <dataset>
                <id>stress_20150910_20150910_160259</id>
                <basedOn>Mimm_20150910_20150910_030922</basedOn>
                <active>false</active>
                <sandbox>true</sandbox>
                <ownedBy>admin</ownedBy>
                <createdOn>2015-09-10T16:04:24.199-04:00</createdOn>
                <createdBy>rtcesupp</createdBy>
                <evaluated>true</evaluated>
                <stopped>false</stopped>
            </dataset>
            <dataset>
                <id>imm_20150910_20150910_140315</id>
                <basedOn>Mimm_20150910_20150910_030922</basedOn>
                <active>true</active>
                <sandbox>true</sandbox>
                <ownedBy>admin</ownedBy>
                <createdOn>2015-09-10T14:04:42.696-04:00</createdOn>
                <createdBy>rtcesupp</createdBy>
                <evaluated>true</evaluated>
                <stopped>false</stopped>
            </dataset>
        </datasets>
</listDatasetsResponse>
```

here is the XSL I used:

```
$ vi dataset.xsl
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

         <xsl:template match="/listDatasetsResponse/datasets/dataset">
          <xsl:value-of select="id"/><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="active='true'">
                     <xsl:text>ACTIVE</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="stopped='true'">
                     <xsl:text>,STOPPED</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="evaluated='true'">
                     <xsl:text>,EVALUATED</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I expected the result of:

```
stress_20150910_20150910_160259    EVALUATED
imm_20150910_20150910_140315       ACTIVE,EVALUATED
```

but what I got is:
        OKstress_20150910_20150910_160259Mimm_20150910_20150910_030922falsetrueadmin2015-09-10T16:04:24.199-04:00rtcesupptruefalseimm_20150910_20150910_140315Mimm_20150910_20150910_030922truetrueadmin2015-09-10T14:04:42.696-04:00rtcesupptruefalse

It seemed like the XSL stylesheet was ignored. Could some one point me to correct XSL template matching syntax?

Comment: You need to override the standard templates to suppress the default processing of nodes that you don't want.

Comment: I'm going to start counting the number of days on which someone *doesn't* ask the "XSLT default namespace" question...

Comment: thanks for your help, gentlemen.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem in your XSL is that none of the XPath expression being used match the element in the source XML. Notice your XML has default namespace declared at the root element :

```
xmlns="http://www.algorithmics.com/schema"
```

Descendant elements without explicit prefix and without local default namespace inherits ancestor default namespace implicitly. To match element in namespace, simply declare a prefix that point to the namespace-uri and use that prefix in your XPath expressions, for example :

```
<xsl:stylesheet .....
    xmlns:d="http://www.algorithmics.com/schema">
    .....
    <xsl:template match="/d:listDatasetsResponse/d:datasets/d:dataset">
        <xsl:value-of select="d:id"/><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        .....
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great. this answered my question. And the example works. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:a="http://www.algorithmics.com/schema"
  version="1.0" >

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="a:listDatasetsResponse/a:datasets/a:dataset" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:dataset">
  <xsl:value-of select="a:id"/>
  <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="a:active|a:stopped|a:evaluated" />
  <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:active[.='true']">
  <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::a:active[.='true']|
                preceding-sibling::a:stopped[.='true']|
                preceding-sibling::a:evaluated[.='true']">,</xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>ACTIVE</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:stopped[.='true']">
  <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::a:active[.='true']|
                preceding-sibling::a:stopped[.='true']|
                preceding-sibling::a:evaluated[.='true']">,</xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>STOPPED</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:evaluated[.='true']">
  <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::a:active[.='true']|
                preceding-sibling::a:stopped[.='true']|
                preceding-sibling::a:evaluated[.='true']">,</xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>EVALUATED</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... or this version ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:a="http://www.algorithmics.com/schema"
  version="1.0" >

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="a:listDatasetsResponse/a:datasets/a:dataset" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:dataset">
  <xsl:value-of select="a:id"/>
  <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="a:active|a:stopped|a:evaluated" />
  <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:active[.='true'] | a:stopped[.='true'] | a:evaluated[.='true']">
  <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::a:active[.='true']|
                preceding-sibling::a:stopped[.='true']|
                preceding-sibling::a:evaluated[.='true']">,</xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="translate( local-name(), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: the example is a little overkill for my task. they are good for learning. thanks.